# Clip line close to polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, geoprocessing, line, clip

I want to clip a line layer that I have, only within a polygon. Used **Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Clip**, and I do get most of line I want that is EXACTLY within the polygon layer. Thing is the line sometimes goes a little bit outside the polygon, but I want to include those parts of the line as well, to get a continuous line. In the picture, the green line is the clipped line, while the pink line is an example of the line that isn't clipped but I want it to be.

Any way to set the clip function to get line with certain radius off the polygon? Or clip manually those parts and then add them to the clipped layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Select by Location](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools/selectbylocation.html)

[image]

by using the polygon to select those areas that it touches then perform your clip as you have done so already, but this time check the "use only selected features".

[image]

You will then have less amount of features to have to clean up in determining those that you want as related to the polygon AOI.

Comment: When I use select by location as you mentioned, I don't see anything selected. Furthermore, with the clip function I don't see any option of checking "use only selected features".

Comment: @nadav, I've updated my response with screenshots to display those points I made about select by location and clip by selected features.

Comment: That's basically what I did. Nothing is being selected when I choose the line to be "layer to select from" and the polygon being the additional layer, with "touches" being checked. I also don't have any box with the "use only selected features" option in clip. Is it a version thing, configurations or what?

Comment: What version are you using? Can you provide screenshots of what your are seeing?

Comment: Using 2.18.12 64 bit on Windows 10. 
[This is how select by location looks like when I use it (GL84 being the line layer.)](https://imgur.com/a/18jwJ)
And
[this is how clip  looks like.](https://imgur.com/a/BIhtD)